# Output creating undesired whitespace

Tags: coldfusion, whitespace

I'm outputting categories with subcategories listed underneath. Each subcategory gets a comma prepended to it if it's not the first item in the loop.

Also, I am only displaying four results, so if the record count is more than four, I need to append `...` to the end of the fourth loop result.

The problem is that in instances where `...` has been applied there is an extra space after each subcategory. See below:
[image]

See how there is a space before the comma?

Code:

```
<ul class="defaultUL" style="float:right;">
            <cfloop query="getParent" startrow="7" endrow="12">
              <cfquery name="getSubCategory" datasource="dss">
                SELECT Name, ID FROM Category WHERE ParentID = #getParent.ID#
                </cfquery>
          <cfset SubNumb = getSubCategory.recordcount>

              <li><h3><a href="?Page=#Application.Utility.qsEncode(getParent.Name)#">#getParent.Name#</a></h3>
                  <cfloop query="getSubCategory" startrow="1" endrow="#SubNumb#">
                    <cfif SubNumb gt 4>
                      <cfif getSubCategory.currentRow lt 4 AND getSubCategory.currentRow gt 1>
                          , #getSubCategory.Name#
              <cfelseif getSubCategory.currentRow eq 1>
                            #getSubCategory.Name#
                            <cfelseif getSubCategory.currentRow eq 4>
                            #getSubCategory.Name#...
                        </cfif>
                      <cfelse>
                        #getSubCategory.Name#,
                    </cfif>

                  </cfloop>
                  </li>
            </cfloop>
            </ul>
```

I made sure that the data in the database didn't have whitespace at the end.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `listAppend` function to construct your string:

```
<cfset subCatList = "" /> <!--- define a variable to hold the list of subcats; variable gets reset for each iteration of outer loop --->
<cfloop query="getSubCategory" startrow="1" endrow="4">
    <!--- listAppend uses , as a the default delimiter. --->
    <cfset subCatList = listAppend(subCatList, getSubCategory.Name) />
</cfloop>
<cfif getSubCategory.RecordCount gt 4>
    <cfset subCatList = listAppend(subCatList,"...") />
</cfif>
<!---- value of subCatList at this point: subcat1,subcat2,subcat3,subcat4... --->
<!--- output subcatlist and fix spacing --->
#replace(subCatList, ",", ", ","all"#
<!--- output is subcat1, subcat2, subcat3, subcat4... --->
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `<cfsetting enablecfoutputonly="true" />` at the top and `<cfsetting enablecfoutputonly="false" />` at the bottom.  Then use `<cfoutput></cfoutput>` to explicitly define what should be output to the browser.